# Empty variable check

Tags: variables, lua

I'm just learning lua, this is my first script with it. How can I check to see if a variable is empty or has something like a line feed in it?

Comment: An "empty" variable in Lua is a variable with the value `nil`. Maybe you are referring to an "empty string", i.e. a string with a length of 0?

Answer (score 31):

You can check whether the value is nil:

```
if emptyVar == nil then
   -- Some code
end
```

Since nil is interpreted as false, you can also write the following:

```
if not emptyVar then
   -- Some code
end
```

(that is, unless you want to check boolean values ;) )

As for the linebreak: You can use the string.match function for this:

```
local var1, var2 = "some string", "some\nstring with linebreaks"
if string.match(var1, "\n") then print("var1 has linebreaks!") end
if string.match(var2, "\n") then print("var2 has linebreaks!") end
```

Comment: The first 2 didn't work, but last one did.  Thanks. `if string.match(variable, "\n") then print("found") else print("not found")`

Comment: You need to understand that a variable with a line feed in it is not empty.  An empty variable has nothing in it. So that is why the first two failed as I assume you tested with a variable with a line feed in.